# Installing Simple Chinese support for solr 5.2

Tags: solr

I am trying to add support for Simple Chinese on my Solr core.  I try add the following to my schema.xml file:

```
<fieldType name="text_zh" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>
```

The get thei following error when reloading the core:

> yirmi:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Could not load conf for core yirmi: Plugin init failure for
>   [schema.xml] fieldType "text_zh": Cannot load analyzer:
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer. Schema file
>   is /var/solr/data/yirmi/conf/schema.xml solr:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Could not load conf for core solr: Error loading solr config from
>   /var/solr/data/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml

When I try

```
<fieldType name="text_zh" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <!--<analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>-->
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.HMMChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                words="org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I get the following error when loading the code:

> ```
> yirmi: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> ```
>
> Could not load conf for core yirmi: Plugin init failure for
>   [schema.xml] fieldType "text_zh": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml]
>   analyzer/tokenizer: Error loading class
>   'solr.HMMChineseTokenizerFactory'. Schema file is
>   /var/solr/data/yirmi/conf/schema.xml
>       solr: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Could not load conf for core solr: Error loading solr config from
>   /var/solr/data/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml

How do I install the necessary plugins in order for the changes in schema.xml to work?

Comment: Have you added the `lucene-analyzers-smartcn-x.y.z.jar` file in `contrib\analysis-extras\lucene-libs` to [the lib statement](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html) in your `solrconfig.xml`?

Comment: Added:
<lib dir="../../../contrib/analysis-extras\lucene-libs" regex="lucene-analyzers-smartcn-5\.2\.1\.jar" />
but still get the same error

Comment: The log should show the library being loaded at startup - verify that it's being loaded.

Comment: 9/6/2018, 11:58:38 AM
 
ERROR
 
null
 
CoreContainer
 
Error creating core [yirmi]: Could not load conf for core yirmi: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType. Schema file is /var/solr/data/yirmi/conf/schema.xml
9/6/2018, 11:58:38 AM
 
ERROR
 
null
 
SolrCore
 
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'yirmi': Unable to create core [yirmi] Caused by: Can't set positionIncrementGap on custom analyzer class org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer

Comment: Error shown when trying to re-add core

Error CREATEing SolrCore 'yirmi': Unable to create core [yirmi] Caused by: Can't set positionIncrementGap on custom analyzer class org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyze

Comment: So you drop the `positionIncrementGap` setting for that field.

Comment: Thanx.  It works.  If you want to put your comments as an answer, I would be happy to upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have added the library files (the `lucene-analyzers-smartcn-x.y.z.jar` file in `contrib\analysis-extras\lucene-libs`) [to your `lib` statement in `solrconfig.xml`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html).

The startup log for Solr should show the library file being loaded.

If you get the error

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'yirmi': Unable to create core [yirmi] Caused by: Can't set `positionIncrementGap` on custom analyzer class `org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyze`

Remove the `positionIncrementGap` setting for that field type, since that setting isn't valid for custom analyzers (which this is).